# Iterate through json array with multiple results

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to figure out how to parse a json response that has multiple results. Here is the response data -

```
 Array
 (
    [id] => 7181676
    [api_request_id] => 20984853
    [user] => 8305
    [vin] => JTDKN3DU7D1643423
    [make] => Toyota
    [model_name] => Prius
    [model_year] => 2013
    [last_updated] => 2019-02-22T01:08:15.628318Z
    [recall_count] => 2
    [status] => ok
    [recalls] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [recall_id] => 15753
                    [recall_age] => 0
                    [nhtsa_id] => 18V684000

                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [recall_id] => 16733
                    [recall_age] => 1
                    [nhtsa_id] => 16V684123

                )
        )
)
```

I would like to loop through to get the recalls[0] and recalls[1] as I wont know how many results there will be so cant do it manually.

The response I am looking for is -

```
2013 Toyota Prius

Recall ID - 1573
Recall Age - 0
Nhtsa Id - 18v684000

Recall ID - 16733
Recall Age - 1
Nhtsa Id - 16v684123
```

Would I do something like this? -

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$responseData = json_decode($data, TRUE);

foreach($responseData as $item){
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: You can do like `echo $item['id'];` to get it's corresponding value which is `7181676`

Comment: Yes thank you I know how I can get the individual values but since there will be an unknown amount of responses I would like to loop through each $responseDara[recalls][0], $responseDara[recalls][1] etc..

Comment: Just check the array while iterating the array after parsing the json data using is_array() method.

Comment: recall_count tells me if there is more than one result, I could use this possibly to know how many times to iterate but not sure on how that would be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop over the `recalls` array in your data; by using a `foreach` loop you don't have to worry how many there are in the array:

```
foreach ($responseData['recalls'] as $key => $recall) {
    echo "recall $key:\n";
    echo "recall id: {$recall['recall_id']}\n";
    echo "recall age: {$recall['recall_age']}\n";
    echo "nhtsa id: {$recall['nhtsa_id']}\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
recall 0: 
recall id: 15753
recall age: 0 
nhtsa id: 18V684000 

recall 1: 
recall id: 16733
recall age: 1 
nhtsa id: 16V684123
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/3i5pT)

Comment: This works perfectly cheers mate! The as $key => $recall breaks out each iteration by the array key I take it? [0], [1] etc..?

Comment: @RyanD yes, `$key` gets the array index from the `recalls` array, and `$recall` gets the contents of that element (in itself another array with 3 elements, `recall_id`, `recall_age`, and `nhtsa_id`)

Answer (score 1):

loop through the array via `for` loop
for example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($responseData['recalls']); $i++) {
    $result = $responseData['recalls'][$i];
    echo $result['recall_id'].'<br>';
    echo $result['recall_age'].'<br>';
    echo $result['nhtsa_id'].'<br>';
}
```